# getting information from a javascript json object

Tags: javascript, url

I imagine this has been posted before but I wasn't able to find a data object specifically like this one. I'm struggling to understand how extract information from this data object in javascript. It's a parsed URL.

```
 data =  URL {
  href: 'http://localhost:8080/test.txt?cat=Mouse',
  origin: 'http://localhost:8080',
  protocol: 'http:',
  username: '',
  password: '',
  host: 'localhost:8080',
  hostname: 'localhost',
  port: '8080',
  pathname: '/test.txt',
  search: '?cat=Mouse',
  searchParams: URLSearchParams { 'cat' => 'Mouse' },
  hash: ''
}
```

I can retrieve the `URLsearchParams`
`data.searchParams`, which returns `{ 'cat' => 'Mouse' }`

What is this data structure called: `{ 'cat' => 'Mouse' }`. I'm confused by the `=>`
And how do I retrieve the two objects 'cat' and 'Mouse' separately inside this data structure?

For example, retrieving then setting a variable equal to the first item, 'cat' and another variable equal to 'Mouse'

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> What is this data structure called: `{ 'cat' => 'Mouse' }`.

That isn't a data structure. It's a visual representation of the data in the `URLSearchParams` object.

Look at the [API documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to see how to access it (e.g. `data.searchParams.entries()`)

---

[There is absolutely nothing JSON related to that.](https://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)